# ppxo_inline_guest_unhandled_error in paypal production

Tags: paypal-rest-sdk

I am trying to implement a paypal checkout payment gateway in my project designed with laravel.

Everything works correctly locally but when I go to production and try to make a purchase the console gives me the following error:

```
ppxo_inline_guest_unhandled_error
```

I want to point out that in production paying through paypal works but if I want to pay through credit card ( Functionality that allows paypal express) that's where the error comes.

Does anyone have any suggestions?
Thanks